# How to get combined column values from multiple tables with different columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine multiple columns from three tables. I could do it using UNION ALL keyword but I am feeling this query what I use is not probably the most efficient

**For example:**

```
create table tbl1
(id int, act varchar(50), stk varchar(50), price int, vol int, amt float);
insert into tbl1 values
(1, 'a1', 's1', 10, 5, 50),
(2, 'a1', 's2', 5, 5, 25),
(3, 'a2', 's1', 15, 3, 45),
(4, 'a2', 's2', 20, 2, 40),
(5, 'a2', 's2', 20, 2, 40);

create table tbl2 (id int, tid int, price int, vol int, amt float);
insert into tbl2 values
(1, 1, 5, 3, 15),(2, 1, 5, 1, 5),(3, 1, 15, 1, 15),
(4, 2, 5, 3, 15),(5, 2, 6, 2, 12);

create table tbl3 (id int, act varchar(10), type int, amt float);
insert into tbl3 values
(1, 'a1', 0, 10),(2, 'a1', 1, 15),
(3, 'a2',1, 5),(4, 'a3',0, 5);`
```

**The query I used**

```
SELECT act,stk,amtFROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
(select act from tbl1 where tbl2.tid = tbl1.id) amt,
(select stk from tbl1 where tbl2.tid = tbl1.id) stk,
amt
from tbl2
```

Is there a way to get the same without using inner select queries twice? could someone please give me the efficient query?

here is the  [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8019bd/72)

**Expected output**  (amt from all three tables where act='a1')

```
ACT     STK     AMT
a1      s1      50
a1      s2      25
a1      s1      15
a1      s1      5
a1      s1      15
a1      s1      10
a1      s1      15
```

Comment: Why not just join the tables? Is there a specific reason for your correlated subqueries???

Comment: I'm not very comfortable with joins, this is the best I could write :)

Comment: It depends on the data but you should be able to just join the tables... I don't think you even need union.   But I'm on my phone so I would need an expected output to make sure everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an explicit `join`:

```
SELECT act, stk, amt
FROM tbl1

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.act as amt, t1.stk, t2.amt
from tbl2 join
     tbl1
     on tbl2.tid = tbl1.id;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! if I had to get only those rows which have act='a1'?

Comment: Then you would add a `where` clause to one or both of the subqueries.

Comment: where clause `where act='a1'` does not work for second table, it still fetches all records http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8019bd/98